# Form address postal code auto-complete https request and CORS workaround

Tags: php, forms, api, cors, postal-code

I'm building a form (**php**) and i want to people put their postal code, and the address gets automatically filled.

I'm having two problems:

1. First, these requests are made by my https page, so if the API that provides me the data is http, it will fail.
2. Second, the cross-origin request all fail. The only https API i found, is of course in other domain... so it don't work.

Do you guys know a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy the API through your own server over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you please tell me how ?

Comment: Make the requests with `cURL`, parrot them back to the browser.